# Streaming data to Bigquery using Appengine

Tags: google-bigquery, google-app-engine-python

I'm collecting data (deriving from cookies installed in some websites) in BigQuery using a streaming approach with a Python code in App Engine. 
The function I use to save the data is the following:

```
def stream_data(data):
    PROJECT_ID = "project_id"
    DATASET_ID = "dataset_id"

    _SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'

    credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=_SCOPE)
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    table = "table_name"
    body = {
            "ignoreUnknownValues": True,                  
            "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest", 
            "rows": [ 
            { 
                "json": data,
            },
            ]
        }
    bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
    bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId=PROJECT_ID, datasetId=DATASET_ID, tableId=table, body=body).execute()
```

I have deployed the solution on two different App Engine instances and I get different result. My question is: how is it possible? 
On the other hand comparing the results with Google Analytics metrics I also notice that not all the data are stored in BigQuery. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Could you please give a little more details about "different result"? What was the result? What was your expectations?

Comment: Doing SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(cookie_id)) from my tables (tables associated with different appengine istances, but same code) on the same time range return different numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there isn't a query exception handling during the insertAll operation. If BigQuery can't write data, you don't catch the exception.

In your last line try this code:

```
bQreturn = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId=PROJECT_ID, datasetId=DATASET_ID, tableId=table, body=body).execute()
logging.debug(bQreturn)
```

In this way, on Google Cloud Platform log, you can easily find a possible error in the insertAll operation.

Answer (score 0):

When using `insertAll()` method you have to keep this in mind:

> Data is streamed temporarily in the streaming buffer which has
>   different availability characteristics than managed storage. Certain
>   operations in BigQuery do not interact with the streaming buffer, such
>   as table copy jobs and API methods like tabledata.list {1}

If you are using the table preview, streaming buffered entries may not be visible.

Doing `SELECT COUNT(*)` from your table should return your total number of entries.

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#missingunavailable-data

Comment: Doing `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(cookie_id))`  from my tables (tables associated with different appengine istances, but same code) on the same time range return different results. Also different wrt 'users' GoogleAnalytics metric.